# how to make a listener when only the left side of the screen is touched using libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm using libgdx and learned how to make onscreen touch action.

`if(Gdx.input.justTouched())`

Don't know how to make action when only left side of the screen is touched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it by `getX();` and `Gdx.graphics.getWidth();`

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
    if (Gdx.input.getX() < Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2){
        // your code here
    } 
}
```

Comment: you got it right and ty, is there any way i can reach out to you, i have one more problem i ve been struggling with and dont think i can present it here really well, if you see this message add me on kik: 'heeeeeyiiiiaa'